# Is there a way to increase the height for TextBlock in Wagtail content panel?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Is there a way to increase the height for TextBlock in Wagtail content panel? I was using RichTextBlock earlier. But this removes aos animations that were added via JS (aos-animate classes were being replaced with data-block-key).

```
content = blocks.TextBlock(
    max_length=1000,
    help_text = 'Text for the About section. Maximum length is 1000 characters',
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/872ps.png)

Answer (score 2):

At this stage `TextBlock` does not support a custom widget but you can pass in a `rows` kwarg to increase the default rows of the field (which will make it higher).

It is worth noting that the TextBlock field will automatically increase in height as you type.

```py
content = blocks.TextBlock(
    max_length=1000,
    rows=15,
    help_text = 'Text for the About section. Maximum length is 1000 characters',
)
```

Read more about the `textarea` input and what `rows` are here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: I have also submitted a PR to update the docs to reflect that `rows` is available - https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/7674

Answer (score 0):

The `rows` method is a nice, clean compromise: an elegant solution.

However, if you want to trigger the `autosize()` method to change the `TextBlock` to be the size of the input, you can use this JavaScript hack in an overridden template:

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var ta = document.getElementById('{{ child.id_for_label }}');
    var evt = new Event('input');
    ta.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
</script>
```

You can see an example here:
https://github.com/FlipperPA/wagtailcodeblock/blob/6d3a36442716155fdc29e1053033ef48a35047ca/wagtailcodeblock/templates/wagtailcodeblock/code_block_form.html#L18

Comment: should this be something that would be a good default behaviour? Maybe worth raising a pull request @FlipperPA

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Not a bad idea, I'll bring this edge case back to the core team to see what they think.